# Escaping python reserved words in xml attributes using the ElementTree library

Tags: python, python-3.x, elementtree

I'm using the ElementTree library and I have an xml tag that has an attribute with the key called "class". Now this is a reserved word in python obviously. Anyone know how to escape this or if it's even possible?

```
ownerNode = et.SubElement(rootNode, "Owner")
referenceNode = et.SubElement(ownerNode, class="org.identity", name="john")
```

^^^ so, how do I escape the class keyword above?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Based on [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.SubElement), it looks like you can pass attributes in a dictionary, with the keys as strings:

```
referenceNode = et.SubElement(ownerNode, "refnode", {"class": "org.identity", "name": "john"})
```

David Lambert, in a [python.org thread](http://bugs.python.org/issue5382) discussing this issue, points out that for a function `f` that only takes keyword arguments, you can do this:

```
def f(**kwargs):
    print(kwargs)

f(**{'class':'sidebar'})
```